# Check if the device is connected to WiFi access point or Mobile hotspot?

Tags: android

Requirement:- Need to run some network calls, only when the device is only connected to an actual WiFi access point, not to a mobile hotspot or cellular data.

We need to check that the currently connected network is a mobile hotspot. Currently, I am using the below code if it is connected to WiFi or Cellular network.

```
    Network activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();

    NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork);

    boolean isWiFi = networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapablities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
```

To identify if the wifi connection is a mobile hotspot, I tried a workaround, by using the below method.

```
connectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered()
```

Along with active connection metered check, the Updated condition is as below

```
boolean isWiFiNotAMobileHotspot = networkCapablities.hasTransport(NetworkCapablities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) && connectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered();
```

Since isActiveNetworkMetered() only helps to identify if we are connected a metered connection (With a restriction of daily/ monthly data limits.)

So for most of the mobile hotspots, it gives the expected results but if the mobile hotspot has an unlimited data plan then isActiveNetworkMetered() returns false.

So, unfortunately, this solution is not the exact way to find if the device is connected to a mobile hotspot.

Kindly help me with the solution to check if the device is connected to a mobile hotspot or not.

Comment: in general, `mobile hotspot` has no difference from `WiFi access point`. In fact, every `mobile hotspot` is the `WiFi access point` itself. Same way some WIFI routers have either SIM-card slot, or USB for mobile modem connection.

Comment: Thanks @Vladyslav for explaining it more, but I want to check if the mobile hotspot/ access point's source is a 2G/3G/4G then I have to ignore it.

Comment: I don;t think you can check the source. only thing I can think of - checking by IP address for the ISP. So if the ISP is in the list of mobile operators - then it is *likely* mobile network

Comment: May you help me with the code that how can we find the ISP from IP address, so that we can figure it out, is it a mobile operator or not.

Comment: there is no such code. You need to find such online API to get ISP from the IP address

Comment: Maybe meassuring the connection speed would be another approach? if the connetion speed is bellow avarage wifi speed you could assume the connection is eiter 2G or 3G. if the connection is above or equla  that assume WIFI or hotspot 4G. Again not clear what is the difference if the hotsport host connection is 2G/3G/4G I would only assume security issues or speed issues??

Comment: Any update on this? @Priyavrat

Comment: @ShailendraMadda Not yet, if you find anything, kindly mark it here.

Answer (score 0):

Once there's a connection change, you can use a broadcast receiver to check whether you're connected to Wi-Fi or not.

```
class NetworkChangeReceiver(private val application: Application) : 
ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

private val NETWORK_CHANGE_TAG = NetworkChangeReceiver::class.java.simpleName
private var networkRequest: NetworkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
.build()

init {
val connectivityManager =     application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, this)
}

override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
super.onAvailable(network)
Timber.i(NETWORK_CHANGE_TAG.plus("onAvailable"))
application.toast("onAvailable")
}

override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
super.onLost(network)
Timber.i(NETWORK_CHANGE_TAG.plus("onLost"))
application.toast("onLost")
    }
}
```

To determine the operator of the connected network, you can get an account from [here](https://ipinfo.io/developers).
Just give a call to `https://ipinfo.io?token=$TOKEN` with your token.

You will be given a JSON response with complete details of the network connected.
For example:

```
ip: "115.xxx.xx.xxx"
city: ""
region: ""
country: "IN"
loc: "2x.0000,7x.0000"
asn: Object
asn: "AS18101"
name: "Reliance Communications Ltd"
domain: "reliance.com"
route: "115.xxx.xx.0/22"
type: "isp"
company: Object
name: "RCOM-Static-DIA"
domain: "reliance.com"
type: "isp"
abuse: Object
address: "Reliance Communication Ltd"
country: "IN"
email: "support@reliance.com"
name: "Antiabus"
network: "115.xxx.xx.0/20"
phone: "xx30334141-5"
```

You can use this service for free, if you require only less than 50K API calls per month.

Comment: Using broadcast receiver is anyway, deprecated. I don't to use any third party Url for same.
Kindly help me with if there is any way via android API's to check that whether it is connected to WiFi access point or Mobile hotspot.

Comment: **Using broadcast receiver is anyway, deprecated.** who told you that, without any third party API, i don't think there's a possible solution for it @Priyavrat

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager Please go through this, It tells the API deprecated from connectivity manager.

Comment: @Priyavrat for every deprecated method there's an alternative method provided by google. There's `NetworkCallback` for that purpose, this is the newer method

Comment: Agree with you @Manoj, that for every deprecated method there is alternative method, I am already using the NetworkCallback by the way, but there is no such way to identify, if we can find whether it is connected to mobile access point or actual wifi access point.

Please let me know, if you can help in the same way, otherwise we can close the discussion here.

Thanks for all you help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198715/discussion-between-manoj-perumarath-and-priyavrat).

Answer (score 0):

I researched a bit on this and got to a point that all the `MOBILE DEVICES` use an ipv4 range of `192.168.43.1 to 192.168.43.254` so it is possible to differentiate mobile AP from ACTUAL wifi on the basis of this.

I wrote a little code to make it clear:

```
  WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
    System.out.println(ip);
    String []wifi_ip = ip.split(".");
    if(wifi_ip[3].equals(43)){
        if(parseInt(wifi_ip[4])>=1 && parseInt(wifi_ip[4])<=254){
            //your code goes here
        }
    }
```

add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

> What this code does ?
>   It actually check the device's IPv4 address and then checks whether ip of the device lies in this range or not.

Comment: I have below queries on same. 

- What if the IP address is IPv6 ?
- wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress() finds the mobile hotspot's IP ? Please confirm.
- As you mentioned 192.168.43.1 to 192.168.43.254, is the range of IPv4, May you please tell me that where it is mentioned ? 

Anyways, thanks for all your efforts here. :)

Comment: hey as per your questions here are the answers,

> if the IP address is based on IPv6 then this method will not work as we don't have enough android devices  assigning IPv6 to their connected devices so its hard to predict the IPv6 addresses based upon their make/model.

> wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress() finds the actual ip assigned to your phone when its connected to WIFI.

> its been tested several times that android devices operate upon this range of IPv4 address
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302220/android-get-ip-address-of-a-hotspot-providing-device

Answer (score 0):

checking the default gateway of the network solves this issue.in general,hotspots gateways are unreachable where as the routers gateways loads their default setup page or login page whenever you hit the default gateway address in the browser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You appear to have misunderstood the question, which was asking how to write code that checks if a device is connected to Wi-Fi.  You've answered a totally unrelated question about fixing network errors.

Answer (score -3):

use this library i will update instantly.

```
implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:3.0.4'
```

Comment: May you please tell me, what this library does. Also it will be great if you share the url/ link to the same.

Comment: you can check connection status mobile data or wifi

Comment: That's not what I need. I need to check if the connected Wifi network is a mobile hotspot.

Kindly check the question.

Comment: This is not an answer. You have provided no information on how this library works, what it does or how it solves the problem. You haven't even provided a link for documentation regarding this library.